# Getting data from elasticsearch into a Javascript Array()

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, elasticsearch, server

I'm trying to program a `nodejs` server that read all documents in an `elsaticsearch` index, and return a `javascript` array that contains the `title` field for each document.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
let elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch')

const esClient = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: '127.0.0.1:9200',
    log: 'error'
});

let titles = new Array()

esClient.search({
    index: 'myindex',
    type: 'mytype',
    body: {
        size: 5,
        from: 0,
        query: {
            match_all: {}
        }
    }
  }).then(function (resp) {
      var hits = resp.hits.hits;
      hits.forEach((hit, index) => titles.push(hit._source.title));

  }, function (err) {
      console.trace('err.message');
});

console.log(titles)
```

But the output of `titles` still empty `[]` after execution

Do you have an idea about how should I code it? if what I want to do is possible with javascript.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes. That's because `.search()` is _asynchronous_. You populate `titles` in the `.then` function (which is good), so it's correct in there (try to log it). Asynchronism means that the lines of code are not executed one by one, in order (like PHP), but only when the data is ready.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)